# Python write csv file with double quotation : String that contains a single quotation mark

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a csv file using `csv.writer` in Python. I wanted to insert double quotation marks around strings, so I added `quotechar` attribute to the writer. However, the problem is if a string contains a single quotation mark, it is messed up.

```
list = []
list.append([1, "foo"])
list.append([2, "bar"])
list.append([3, "foo's bar"])

with open('list.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quotechar = "'")
    for row in list:
        row[1] = '\"' + row[1] + '\"'   
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Using the code above, I get following as `list.csv` file

```
1,"foo"
2,"bar"
3,'"foo''s bar"'
```

I would like to have the 3rd row to be `"foo's bar"` without any extra single quotations. How can I properly apply double quotations to a string that contains a single quotation?

Comment: If you do that, the literal double quotes that you added to the value won't be parsed correctly. They'll be treated as the field delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `quoting` argument to handle putting quotes around non-numeric columns. This also spares you from having to add the double quotes to a row separately.

```
with open('list.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in list:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This writes the desired output

```
1,"foo"
2,"bar"
3,"foo's bar"
```

Comment: I can't adequately understand why this works, but it does work. Thanks!

Comment: Having read some of the `csv` documentation, the previous answer was a lucky break. setting `quotechar` only worked because there were no instances of the new quotechar in the input. `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` solves the problem more properly